# Using HTML5 Canvas and Socket.io server to position user (player) always in center after movement

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

In some .io games, the player always appears in the center of the screen, and when moving around, stays positioned there regardless of coordinates.
As I have been making a socket.io HTML5 canvas game, I would like to know how to implement this in my own game. I figure that this involves some math, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
What I am doing now is making the new player at the coordinates (50, 50), and determining their coordinates based on a socket event sent on keydown/up, as shown.

For reference, here is the part of the server rendering the player and determining coordinates:

```js
gameState.players[socket.id] = {
        x: 50,
        y: 60,
        width: 2,
        height: 2
    }
    setInterval(() => {
        socket.emit('gamestate', gameState);
    }, 1000 / 60);   

    socket.on('movement', (playerMovement) => {
        const player = gameState.players[socket.id];
        
        if (playerMovement.left){
            player.x -= 2;
        }
        if (playerMovement.right){
            player.x += 2;
        }
        if (playerMovement.up){
            player.y -= 2;
        }
        if (playerMovement.down){
            player.y += 2;
        }
    });
```

and here is the part of the client-side code that sends the events and draws the players.

```js
function renderGame(uname){
    socket.emit('join', {uname: uname});

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
    if ((event.keyCode == '38')||event.keyCode == '87'){
        playerMovement.up = true;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }else if ((event.keyCode == '40')||event.keyCode == '83'){
        playerMovement.down = true;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }else if ((event.keyCode == '37')||event.keyCode == '65'){
        playerMovement.left = true;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }else if ((event.keyCode == '39')||event.keyCode == '68'){
        playerMovement.right = true;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }

});
document.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
    if ((event.keyCode == '38')||event.keyCode == '87'){
        playerMovement.up = false;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }else if ((event.keyCode == '40')||event.keyCode == '83'){
        playerMovement.down = false;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }else if ((event.keyCode == '37')||event.keyCode == '65'){
        playerMovement.left = false;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }else if ((event.keyCode == '39')||event.keyCode == '68'){
        playerMovement.right = false;
        socket.emit('movement',playerMovement);
    }
});

socket.on('gamestate', (gameState) => {
    for (let player in gameState.players) {
        drawPlayer(gameState.players[player]);
    }
});

}

function drawPlayer(player){
    var context = document.getElementById('board').getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(player.x, player.y, player.width, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'orange';
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

}
```

My idea right now is to define a relative coordinate system which the server communicates back to the user. Running a loop, it would determine if the other players' relative coordinate x and y were withing 100 units of the player, at which point the players would see each other on the canvas system separated by that many units.

Any better ideas?